# Gradle build folder not showing up after installing the Gradle Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I have a project that I use gradle to build.  Before I installed Gradle Eclipse plugin, I was able to see the gradle build folder in Eclipse.  But after installing the plugin (Buildship) and creating and building a new Gradle project, I am no longer able to see the build folder in Project Explorer or Package Explorer or Navigator.  I am able to see the build folder and the jar file from Windows Explorer.  I tried to change the settings from Customize View..., but it didn't solve the issue.   Can someone please let me know how to let the build folder show up ? Thanks.

This is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'com.ii.mainClass'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

 sourceCompatibility = 1.7
 targetCompatibility = 1.7

 dependencies {
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.1'
      compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.1'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-beans:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-context:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-core:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework:spring-expression:4.2.0.RELEASE'
      compile 'org.springframework.xd:spring-xd-tuple:1.0.4.RELEASE'
   }
```

Comment: I still use STS, but Buildship might be marking the build folder as derived or have an exclude pattern. You might look at the project's build path in Eclipse's project properties view.

Answer (score 8):

I found the solution in a topic on the Gradle forum (https://discuss.gradle.org/t/setting-eclipse-native-library-location/11075/2).

The plugin installs a resource filter with an exclude pattern, which you can manually remove in the project's properties (Resource -> Resource Filters).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This workaround did the job.

Answer (score 8):

[image: You can disable filter through customize filter in project explorer options, and uncheck the gradle build option in it.]

You can disable filter through customize filter in project explorer options, and uncheck the gradle build option in it.

Comment: If anyone is wondering where this dialogue box opens, There is a small down arrow icon(View Menu) just beside minimize the folder view -> Filters and Customization

Answer (score 0):

Select the project and then select the project menu as given in the below image.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsAuo.jpg)

And then uncheck the 'Grale build folder' and then you can see the build folder as shown in below image.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Tqja.jpg)